# How to distinguish rows in a database table on the basis of two or more columns while returning all columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to distinguish Rows on the basis of two or more columns value of the same table at the same time returns all columns from the table.
Ex: I have this table
  [DB Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVevn.png)

I want my result to be displayed as: filter on the basis of type and Number only. As in abover table type and Number for first and second Row is same so it should be suppressed in result.

```
txn item Discrip Category type   Number            Mode
60  2    Loyalty    L     6174  XXXXXXX1390         0
60  4    Visa       C     1600  XXXXXXXXXXXX4108    1
```

I have tried with sub query but yet unsuccessful. Please suggest what to try.
Thanks

Comment: mention your query plz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want with `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type, number order by item) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I tried this bro. But unfortunately it is removing all the rows where type and number combination was a match.